# Connotation of the spelling "Расея"

Tags: выбор-слова, этимология, toponyms

Are there any guidelines on using *Расея* over *Россия*? Is the former archaic or comical? Grandiloquent, ridiculous? Something else? Was it perhaps the actual official name of the country at some point in the past?

As a bonus, do both come from Old Church Slavonic?

Comment: It is ironic usage. Currently no one speaks or spells this word this way seriously.

Comment: Not offensive, just comical. Similar to **Раша**, which sounds same as Russia. To play with sounds.

Answer (score 4):

Расея is a "lower class" equivalent of Россия (see [here](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/8930/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%8F)).

Usually when someone uses this word he or she means that something that happened, or some idea, or the way the person behaves is because of "backwoods mentality" - the way people act or think in rural areas: "Эх, Расея!" as opposed to modern ways of doing things.

The word form is imitating the way the people in some provinces speak.

As for origins of the word, [according to Vasmer](http://fasmer-dictionary.info/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/568/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F) the first occurense of the word is dated 1517. Before that time the word Русь was used.

The word Русь dates back to 9 century, and has Scandinavian origins.

Answer (score 3):

I think the word is derogatory and intentionally wrongly-spelled to underline the low culture of either the speaker or the country.